# Reference Request: Central Curvature "Fix"

Tags: a-infinity-algebras, floer-homology, lagrangian-submanifolds, fukaya-category

**Context:** In Lagrangian-Floer theory, the (an) $\mathbf{A}_\infty$-algebra of a Lagrangian is curved. However, the curvature is central. One consequence of this is that you can get an uncurved $\mathbf{A}_\infty$-algebra by ignoring $m_0$ and taking the same multiplications $m_k$ for $k > 0$. This has been referred to as the standard "fix" to avoid thinking about curved $\mathbf{A}_\infty$-algebras. (Curvature affects the deformations, however.)

**Question:** Does anyone know if it has ever been made explicit in the literature that this is what Lagrangian-Floer theorist do. If so, what is the first reference in which this was made explicit?